# Land of the Deep but not Profound

Tags: riddle, rhyme

In the land of the deep, but not profound,
We just might see a deer.
You shouldn't make a single sound,
And must respect their seer.

The people there are very odd,
and have strange tastes.
They do not like fish, or even cod,
And really hate their waists.

They do love food, but hate to eat,
Eggs might just be best.
They think Mississippi is really neat,
but don't like home to rest.

They love to kill, they hate life,
But murder is not liked.
Any knife will cause strife.
but wheels get them psyched.

So tell me now, what it may be,
that sets this word apart.
A tag is missing. They love to see,
To roll they like, but not to start.

Comment: All I can think of is Fannee Doolee from Zoom (PBS TV show not the superhero movie)

Comment: This riddle works well vocally. Set it up with a couple examples (they like to kill, and hate life), and let your friends guess things until they figure it out. More challenging when you can't see the words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The people of this land only like words that contain double letters, d*ee*p, d*ee*r, o*dd* etc., Mi*ss*i*ss*i*pp*i being a extra likeable example.